# Scope of Scala's implicit class conversion

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

Scala seems to apply the implicit class conversion on the largest possible expression, as in the following example:

```
scala> class B { def b = { println("bb"); true } }
defined class B

scala> class A { def a = { println("aa"); new B } }
defined class A

scala> (new A).a.b
aa
bb
res16: Boolean = true

scala> class XXX(b: => Boolean) { def xxx = 42 }
defined class XXX

scala> implicit def toXXX(b: => Boolean) = new XXX(b)
toXXX: (b: => Boolean)XXX

scala> (new A).a.b.xxx
res18: Int = 42
```

I'm very happy about this fact, but my question is that which part of the SLS specifies this behavior? Why does it not evaluate `(new A).a.b` to `true` first for example, and just apply the conversion on that value?

Comment: @Daniel Interesting, since this behavior currently makes scalaz's `(file: java.io.File).exists.pure[IO]` work as supposed (`io(file.exists)`), otherwise the IO operation would actually be performed outside of IO.

Comment: Update: there is an ongoing discoussion at http://groups.google.com/group/scala-language/browse_thread/thread/c8327695dfdceecd

Comment: I suggest you answer your question with the information provided there. The answer makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by Ryan Hendrickson on the mailing list:

[The definition] you're looking for is in Section 7.3, in the list of the three situations in which views are applied:

1. In a selection e.m with e of type T, if the selector does not denote a member
   of T. In this case, a view v is searched which is applicable to e and whose result
   contains a member named m. The search proceeds as in the case of implicit
   parameters, where the implicit scope is the one of T. If such a view is found,
   the selection e.m is converted to v(e).m.

So the compiler can only generate something that is semantically equivalent to v(e).m, and as you've demonstrated, when by-name parameters are involved

```
val x = e
v(x).m
```

is not semantically equivalent to `v(e).m`.

Answer (score 0):

The line containing the implicit conversion

```
(new A).a.b.xxx
```

gets converted by the compiler (ie, at compile-time) into

```
toXXX((new A).a.b).xxx
```

We can see this if you use the `-Xprint:typer` option when starting Scala.

```
private[this] val res3: Int = $line5.$read.$iw.$iw.toXXX(new $line2.$read.$iw.$iw.A().a.b).xxx;
```

Since this conversion happens at compile-time and not run-time, it would be impossible for Scala to evaluate `(new A).a.b` to `true` before applying the conversion.  Thus, the behavior you get is exactly the same as if you has just written `toXXX((new A).a.b).xxx` in the first place.

Comment: But what prevents the compiler from converting into `val x = (new A).a.b; toXXX(x).xxx` ? What guarantees the observed semantics?